# Keeping special characters in `System.Diagnostics.Process.ErrorDataReceived`

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to fork an instance of Git and redirect its output into my own program. I'm using the following minimal code:

```csharp
using (var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        Arguments = $"clone --progress --bare {RepositoryUrl} {destinationDirectory}"
    }
})
{
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Running this code produces the following output:

```
Cloning into bare repository '<redacted>'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects:  20% (1/5)
remote: Counting objects:  40% (2/5)
    <snip>
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5)
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects:  33% (1/3)
remote: Compressing objects:  66% (2/3)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Receiving objects:   0% (1/4973)
Receiving objects:   1% (50/4973)
    <snip>
Receiving objects:  46% (2288/4973)
Receiving objects:  47% (2338/4973)
Receiving objects:  48% (2388/4973), 6.95 MiB | 13.89 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  49% (2437/4973), 6.95 MiB | 13.89 MiB/s
    <snip>
Receiving objects:  98% (4874/4973), 18.66 MiB | 18.66 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  99% (4924/4973), 18.66 MiB | 18.66 MiB/s
remote: Total 4973 (delta 0), reused 5 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (4973/4973), 18.66 MiB | 18.66 MiB/s
Receiving objects: 100% (4973/4973), 21.21 MiB | 17.53 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:   0% (0/1261)
Resolving deltas:   1% (14/1261)
    <snip>
Resolving deltas: 100% (1261/1261)
Resolving deltas: 100% (1261/1261), done.
```

In a terminal, the repeated lines actually overwrite each other so that a single incrementing counter is displayed. This is done by outputting carriage returns, which reset the terminal's cursor to the first column.

On the other hand, it seems that the `Process` infrastructure strips all line feeds (as expected) *as well as carriage returns* before handing Git's output back to my code. I cannot just put them back in myself as not all of Git's output is supposed to use them, and I cannot tell which ones do once they are stripped.

**How can I disable special character stripping within `Process`' asynchronous output redirection, to receive the output as-is?**

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be hardcoded in the `AsyncStreamReader` (reference source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/AsyncStreamReader.cs.html#4a55a79566963957) used internally by the `BeginErrorReadLine`/`ErrorDataReceived` logic. I am not sure, but perhaps "manually" polling the error channel TextReader might help you get your hands on the complete error output including any control characters..

Comment: I don't really know the command line arguments for git from the top of my head, but i wouldn't be surprised if there were command line options that can tailor output to be better suited for redirected output...

Comment: @elgonzo *Argh*. Looks like I'm about to drop back down to C-style buffer twiddling. Joy. I have checked, Git does not provide such fine-grained control for progress information.